# Laravel form insert in one go

Tags: php, forms, laravel, insert

I created a normal HTML form with 10+ fields. One of the fields is the submit button (obviously nobody wants to store it in database). I'm trying to save data in the table with this statement in the **Product** model:

In controller:

```
$id = Product::saveFormData(Input::all());
```

In model:

```
$id = DB::table('products')->insertGetId($data);
```

It is giving me the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'btncreateproduct' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `url_key`, `sku`, `quantity`, `price`, `specialprice`, `description`, `preorder`, `page_title`, `header_data`, `custom_json_data`, `btncreateproduct`, `category_id`) values (abc, aaa, bbb, 11, 2222, 1111, abcasdf, no, asdf, asdf, asdf, Create Product, 2))'

Now, first of all, why it is considering `btncreateproduct` as a field. I do not want to specify the list of fields in my model as I want this code to be scalable (user can add any number of fields).

Secondly, the values abc, aaa are not like 'abc', 'aaa'

Which means at the current moment, it is not considering them as string values. Although they are defined **varchar** in the database.

Comment: Hi!

Can you post your HTML?

It is possible that your submit button is not type `submit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About the button**

The reason why your button is part of your submission is that you put the attribute name.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) for reference.

You can test with this:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <button type="submit" name="test" value="Submit1">Submit A</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit2">Submit B</button>
</form>
```

**About creating entries in the db**

What you are trying to do in your code is called [Massive Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel) and is really dangerous and insecure.

So as suggested you should use your model using the `Product::create()`.
In addition to that in the Model `Product` you have to insert the property `$fillable`.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {
    // this is just an example, modify this part in accord to your needs
    protected $fillable = [`name`, `url_key`, `sku`, `quantity`, `price`, `specialprice`, `description`, `preorder`, `page_title`, `header_data`, `custom_json_data`, `category_id`];

    // other code here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks borracciaBlu it works. What I want is a scalable solution like we add custom attributes in Magento to products. Anyways, I will try to figure out some solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what possible reason are you using QueryBuilder `DB::table('products')...` instead of the model itself for saving a new product?

In any case you can do something along the lines of

```php
$input = Input::except(['btncreateproduct']);
$newProduct = Product::create($input);
$id = $newProduct->id;
```

That being said you **better** do a proper validation and type casting and manually assign these values, because at some point either table schema or form will change and break your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks peterm, I will avoid the DB::table.