# Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Post]

Tags: php, laravel

While inserting data in Mysql I have encountered the following error:

*"Add [title] to the fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Post]."*

Here is my code:

```
$post = Post::create([
'title' => $request->input('title'),
'body' => $request->input('body')
]);
```

While when I use another way to insert data, it is working fine:
Following code is working fine :

```
//Create Post
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->input('title');
$post->body = $request->input('body');
$post->save();
```

Could anyone explain why an upper portion of the code is throwing an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Mass Assignment" mean in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Add a title to the fillable array in your model Post, to allow saving through creating and massive methods

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Could you please specify which approach is better?

Comment: Or you can use protected $guarded = []; and make fillable every field, buy for security reasons its recommended to use $fillable and inserting every fillabled field there

Answer (score 64):

The alternative to `protected $fillable = ['title'];` would be :

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

and leave it as an empty array, without the need to define anything inside.
It is the exact opposite of `$fillable`, sort of like telling the database to accept everything, except the fields you specify inside the `$guarded` array.

Comment: Yup, way easier than adding every single field in the $fillable array.

Comment: While easier, this introduces security issues. Someone can modify your form and enter an `id` field, and update their id in the DB. Or `salary` or any other sensitive field.

Comment: Array to string conversion exception error

Comment: @MohamedRaza that's a different kind of error and has nothing to do with this. Check you code.

Comment: Okay @Armin got it

Comment: This should be standard, default behaviour for all models.  Maybe I'll make all my models extend another class that has this line in it.

Answer (score 17):

For $fillable all

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Answer (score 11):

For mass assignment you should define "Fillable array" in your model (App\Post)

So your model should be something like this:

```
    class Post extends Model
    {

        protected $fillable = ['title','body']; //<---- Add this line
// ... 
}
```

More information:
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment][1]

Answer (score 7):

Add a title to the fillable array in your model Post.

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is (included in)/(very similar to) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53793892/8068675), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

This error appeared because you didn't declare a variable in your Model - you should define it in your class like so;

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

All Laravel Models when created, don't contain any fillable property.

To allow them to accept field data and insert to database, we must first allow them in our model.

In your Post model, add this line:

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but I had this problem and the solution was completely different.

Inside my PostController I was checking auth, then finding:

```
Post::where('slug', $oldSlug)->first()->update([
            'image_url' => $request->image_url,
            'slug' => $newSlug,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'catagory' => $request->catagory,
        ]);
```

I was looking at it trying to understand why it didn't like "image_url", screaming "Add ['image_url'] to fillable property to allow mass assignment".

I realized that I added the `->first()` to make sure I was only getting one post, but since all slugs are validated and verified to be unique, I dropped the `->first()`.

```
Post::where('slug', $oldSlug)->update([
        'image_url' => $request->image_url,
        'slug' => $newSlug,
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'catagory' => $request->catagory,
    ]);
```

Like magic, it works.

If anyone with more advanced knowledge can explain *why* it worked, I would be very interested in knowing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Post model, there will be a `$fillable` array variable which you have to add 'title'.

For More info: [What does "Mass Assignment" mean in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

the best option to prevent one field

```
Post::create($request->except('_token'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts)

> Alternatively, you may use the create method to "save" a new model
> using a single PHP statement. The inserted model instance will be
> returned to you by the create method:

```
use App\Models\Flight;

$flight = Flight::create([
    'name' => 'London to Paris',
]);
```

> However, before using the create method, you will need to specify
> either a fillable or guarded property on your model class. These
> properties are required because all Eloquent models are protected
> against mass assignment vulnerabilities by default.

Answer (score -1):

**Laravel 9** - Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Post] - ERROR

For mass assignment defined "Fillable array" on the model (App\Post)

So post model should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['title','body','excerpt','is_published','image_path','is_published','min_to_read'];
}
```

This worked for me!