# Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Task]

Tags: php, laravel

I can't figure out the problem, I tried the ones on stack overflow and did not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image: error]

The TaskController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('tasks.index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);

        Task::create([
            'title' => $request->title
        ]);

        session()->flush('msg', 'Task has been created');
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53793841/12635334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error shows you, you have to add `title` to your `$fillable` model properties... Read this part of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts)...

```php
protected $fillable = ['title'];
```

---

As [Tem Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) said, you can also read [this one](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: Beat me to it :) More useful documentation too: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: yeah it is like this protected $fillable = ['title']; , and I tried guarded also did'nt work

Comment: Show us your `TaskController.php` and your Model please.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I edited the question, sorry my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: @MeshaelAbdullah it is strange, it should be working, you have everything as expected, I think this will not fix anything but try running `composer dump-autoload` on the terminal

Comment: @matiaslauriti it gave me this - Class App\Task located in ./app/Providers/Task.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping. do you know what it meant ?

Comment: @MeshaelAbdullah Yes, your problem is that you have that file in `app/Providers`, but the namespace is `App`, so it should be in `app` folder. The namespace must be the same as the folder. Move the file to `app`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yeah it worked, thank you so much

Comment: @MeshaelAbdullah No problem ! Read about PSR-4 [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4), remember to mark the answer as accepted !

Comment: @matiaslauriti sure, thanks !