# larvael form submit to database giving error

Tags: laravel

i am new to laravel and i am trying to submit form into data base but i am getting error i dont know why
i have added the screen shot along with that controller
when i do  `dd($REQUEST->all())` i am getting the form data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InventoryController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    return view('invetory.index');
}
  public function sales(){
    return view('invetory.sale');
}
  public function create(Request $REQUEST){
    
// dd($REQUEST->all());
inventories::Create($REQUEST->all());
    
}
}
```

[image]

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/inventory', 'App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController@index')->name('map');
Route::get('/inventory/sales', 'App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController@sales');


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::post('/inventory', 'App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController@create')->name('invetory.create');
```

[image]

Comment: Add more information. You didn't bring inventories namespace here.

Comment: Can you show your routes as well? (`web.php`)

Comment: @MuhammadHassanJaved which file do u need?

Comment: @meon most likely the inventories model you are using.

Comment: Which namespace is `inventories` in? (You'd need to `use namespace\inventories` in your controller). Btw, are you sure the model name is  `inventories` and not `Inventory`, which you have a `use App\Inventory` already in your code?

Comment: @brombeer i have added my project stucture

Comment: @meon use `use App\Models\Inventory`

Comment: @meon you need to specify what ```inventories``` is. Or you might use your model eith with ```as``` keyword i.e, ```use App\Models\Inventory as inventories;``` in your controller or with it's own name as ```Inventory::Create($REQUEST->all());``` inside create function.

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar i tryed as u asked`` Class "App\Inventory" not found`` i am getinng this error now

Comment: As mentioned, there is no `inventories` model. Change `use App\Inventory` to `use App\Models\Inventory` and `inventories::Create(...)` to `Inventory::create(...)`. I suggest you take a little tutorial on classes and namespaces

Comment: @brombeer ok now i got this error ` Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Inventory].`

Comment: @meon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793841/add-title-to-fillable-property-to-allow-mass-assignment-on-app-post

Comment: @meon So do that. Just in case you don't know how, there's Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment Good luck

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar i dont follow can u explain

Comment: @meon please follow the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your code the controller should look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InventoryController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    return view('invetory.index');
  }
  public function sales(){
    return view('invetory.sale');
  }
  public function create(Request $request){
    Inventory::Create($request->all());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the namesapce of inventory to `use App\Models\Inventory;`

and also , inside *create* *function* use :

Inventory::Create($request->all());

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to import Inventory Model in your controller

```
use App\Models\Inventory;
```

Add the given line in top of your code where you call other classes.

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Inventory $inventory)
    {
        $inventory->create($request->all());
    }
}
```

And here how the function looks like.

You can also use PHP extensions like PHP IntelliSense and PHP IntelliPhense to avoid such errors. These extensions can provide you with proper suggestions for class methods, functions, and more.