# Add [0] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\posts]

Tags: laravel, database, error-handling, controller

While inserting data into Mysql I have encountered the following error:

"Add [0] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\posts]"

Here is my code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        posts::where('id', $id)->first()->update([
            $this->validate($request, [
                'title' => 'required|max:25',
                'description' => 'required|max:255',
                'price' => 'required',
            ])
        ]);

        return redirect(route('posts'));
    }
```

When adding this to the model some other error occures

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

new errorcode: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `posts` set `0` = {"title":"Auto","description":"hallo, das ist eine Beschreibung","price":"123"}, `posts`.`updated_at` = 2022-12-26 01:56:20 where `id` = 1)"

Comment: you are passing an array inside an array to `update` ... `validate` already returns an associative array of the data, you are then wrapping it in a new array (which only has 1 element and the index is `0`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add \[title\] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on \[App\Post\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793841/add-title-to-fillable-property-to-allow-mass-assignment-on-app-post)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

`$this->validate` returns an array; there is no need to add another array around it; try this instead:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    posts::where('id', $id)->first()->update(
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:25',
            'description' => 'required|max:255',
            'price' => 'required',
        ])
    );

    return redirect(route('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It should be:

```
    class posts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['title','description', 'price'];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).