# all value is not inserted in my database (laravel-5.7)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I try to insert a value into the database by a form in Laravel but my all value's is not inserted.

Insert only **email,password,created_date**

**Here is my code of migration**:-

```
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->string('dob');
        $table->string('religion');
        $table->string('mtn');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('district');
        $table->string('upozila');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Here is my code of controller**:-

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validation($request);
    User::create($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
}

public function validation($request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'fname' => 'required|max:255',
    'lname' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
    'phone' => 'required|max:255',
    'gender' => 'required|max:255',
    'dob' => 'required|max:255',
    'religion' => 'required|max:255',
    'mtn' => 'required|max:255',
    'country' => 'required|max:255',
    'city' => 'required|max:255',
    'district' => 'required|max:255',
    'upozila' => 'required|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:6',
    'confirm_password' =>'required|min:6|same:password',
     ]);
}
```

Here is my array = $request->all();

```
_token     "wDRoDeLkOFX5re5nba2Ufv5pr0iKzYVCr0tK9EFE"
fname      "nirab" 
lname      "nirax" 
email      "is@gmail.com" 
phone      "988907" 
gender     "male" 
dob        "2018-12-03" 
religion   "male" 
mtn        "male" 
country    "male" 
city       "male" 
district   "male" 
upozila    "male"
password   "1234567" 
confirm_password    "1234567"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `create` method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Fillable you specify which fields are mass-assignable in your model, you can do it by adding the special variable `$fillable` to the model. So in the model:

```
    class users extends Model {
          protected $fillable = ['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone', 'gender', 'dob', 'religion', 'mtn', 'country', 'city', 'district', 'upozila', 'password']; 
          //only the field names inside the array can be mass-assign
    }
```

**More details**: you can read my answer and you can easily understand here What does “Mass Assignment” mean in Laravel ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel/49669781#49669781))

Comment: thanks ...but iam edit in app/user.php on protected $fillable ..now its working

Answer (score 0):

It is a protection mechanism of Laravel,
Read a bit more here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

When you use create, make sure your model has a "$fillable" property, like so:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'gender',
    'dob',
    'religion',
    'mtn',
    'country',
    'city',
    'district',
    'upozila',
    'password'
];
```

**Also, pay attention that your password should be hashed before you store it in your database.**

Comment: you can also do protected $guarded[] and anything you put in the array is not mass fillable.

Comment: He also has to unset `_token` from the request