# function create() insert a date

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 fields which are id, name, prenom, **date_naissance**. 
When I insert a recording in my phymyadmin, I don't have a problem with the date_naissance.

[image]

However, when I try to insert a date_naissance in my insert form, I have an error message.

[image]

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'date_naissance' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `eleves` (`nom`, `prenom`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Benoit, Piret, 2019-03-07
>   22:31:24, 2019-03-07 22:31:24))

Do you see the problem ?

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.eleves.create', compact('eleves'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nom' => 'required|string',
        'prenom' => 'required|string',
        'date_naissance' => 'required|date'
    ]);
   Eleve::create($request->all());
   return redirect()->route('eleves.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
}
```

**My View create**

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('eleves.store')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <fieldset class="form-group">
     <label for="form-group-input-1">Nom</label>
     <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
     <label for="form-group-input-1">Prénom</label>
     <input type="text" name="prenom" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
     <label for="form-group-input-1">Date naissance</label>
     <input type="date" name="date_naissance" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
  </fieldset>

  <a href="{{route('eleves.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Back</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Valider</button>
</form>
```

**Model:**

```
class Eleve extends Model
{
    //
    protected  $fillable = ['nom', 'prenom'];
    protected $dates = ['date_naissance'];
```

Comment: can you show the code of your view (form)? Looks like you are not passing a field called `date_naissance` and SQL does not know how to add a default, therefore it gives the error

Comment: Make sure in the table schema you allow nulls for `date_naissance` unless you can confirm it will always have a date.

Comment: Can you print your `$request->all()` and show it? Check you dump result and make sure you allow null value by default for `date_naissance`.

Comment: @ArSeN: I have edited my first message... thanks

Comment: I guess you have a `$fillable` array in `Eleves` Model , and `date_naissance` ain't in there

Comment: @user11124425 well thanks but it does not really show much since there are no input fields (which would get submitted upon form submission) what so ever, can you show the *rendered* form?

Comment: @Daniel G: It  must always have a date

Comment: @ArSeN: Indeed, I have edited...

Comment: @user11124425 as Shuyi already pointed out, if you want to fill it, which you are doing with `Eleve::create($request->all());`, you'll have to add the `date_naissance` key to the `$fillable` property as well

Comment: @SundarBan: I see this, `array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "_token" => "krCfSEdmggz3yKLf1DHNoXLqEGAmSi9r532Gto2z"
    "nom" => "Leroi"
    "prenom" => "Mathieu"
    "date_naissance" => "1990-01-01"
  ]
]`

Comment: @ ArSeN: thank you Arsen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model

```
class Eleve extends Model
{
    //
    protected  $fillable = ['nom', 'prenom','date_naissance']; // missing date_naissance here.
    protected $dates = ['date_naissance'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify either a *`fillable`* or *`guarded`* attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Fillable you specify which fields are mass-assignable in your model, you can do it by adding the special variable `$fillable` to the model. So in the model you need to add also ***`date_naissance`***:

```
class Eleve extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'prenom','date_naissance']; //only the field names inside the array can be mass-assign
    protected $dates = ['date_naissance'];
}
```

**More details:** you can easily understand here [What does “Mass Assignment” mean in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel/49669781#49669781)