# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need some help with this...I'm making a function for tags with a tutorial, but in my database ( `post_tag` ), my `post_id` isn't saved, only `tag_id` and `id`.In my `posts` table, after create a post I receive the `id` of post, but here, in my `post_tag` isn't.Do you know why guys...?

**My controller**

```
public function create(){

        $tags = Tag::all();

        return view('posts.create')->withTags($tags);
    }
public function store(Request $request )
    {



        $data = request()->validate([

            'caption' => 'required|max:255',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);
        $post = new Post;

        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);



        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1600, 1100);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $data['caption'],
            'image' => $imagePath,
        ]);



         return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

**My create_post_tag_table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');

            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

        });
    }
```

**My create_posts_table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a problem in the model of those tables. Since you are not using Laravel's convention for naming tables, you have to specific the foreign keys.

Comment: Maybe should I share Post and Tag models?

Comment: I answered something yesterday that sounds very similar.  Please take a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031847/general-error-1364-field-doesnt-have-a-default-value/57031950#57031950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was this:

```
$post = auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption' => $data['caption'],
        'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);
```

I just added this to my code, and all was ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new **Post** object, but you have not saved it yet in this line:

```
$post = new Post;
```

Thus, in this line, immediately following:

```
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
```

**There is no `id` in the database for this post as yet** (nor will there be an `id` on the **Post** model), and thus sync will fail every time because it can't find the `id`.

After you new up the **Post** object, `save()` it and then you can sync.

---

On a different note that may help in other ways, your post model has a big int as its `id`:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {    
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
}
```

But your post_tag table is only an integer. This mismatch may cause some issues.  Suggest changing to match:

```
Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned(); // <--- suggest change this to bigInteger
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but since you don't have the onUpdate or onDelete properties in your table associated with your foreign keys, it could be the problem.