# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to insert data into database but it says:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_name' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `categories` (`updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (2019-07-23 02:34:10, 2019-07-23 02:34:10))

**My controller:**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //dd($request->all());
    $request->validate([
        'category_name'         => 'required',
        'category_description'  => 'required',
        'category_slug'         => 'required',
        'category_image'        => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $image = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images'));

    $category = Category::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

**My model:**

```
   protected $fillable = [
     'categry_name', 'categry_description', 'categry_slug', 'categry_image'
   ];
```

This is a **Database table:** [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spelling mistakes in your model as per your controller.
You have to change your model to

```
   protected $fillable = [
     'category_name', 'category_description', 'category_slug', 'category_image'
   ];
```

If you use database migration, you have to update all the columns like:

```
       Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('category_name');
            $table->string('category_description');
            $table->string('category_slug');
            $table->string('category_image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

While designing your database, be very precise else use '**[nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)**' in columns which you are unsure if they are mandatory. Nullable declaration in migration is:

```
       $table->string('category_name')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

`categry_name` in your `$fillable` is misspelt. It's missing an `e`

Answer (score 0):

According to your controller, your model has spelling mistakes

```
class categories extends Model {
          protected $fillable = ['category_name', 'category_description', 'category_slug', 'category_image']; 
          //only the field names inside the array can be mass-assign
}
```

More details: [What does “Mass Assignment” mean in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel/49669781#49669781)