# Laravel 5.8 polymorphic relation `nullableMorphs` not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, polymorphic-relationship

I have a table for attachments, that has polymorphic relation with other tables. I want to upload a file on file select and insert it to the `attachments` table, but this record is not related to any parent table until the parent record is created, so for this two fields `attachable_id`, and `attachable_type` should be nullable.
Following is attachments table migration:

```
schema::table('attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->nullableMorphs('attachable');
});
```

But when I create the attachment record, it shows an error.

```
$attachment = new Attachment();
$attachment->name = 'name';
.........
.........
$attachment->save();

"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'attachable_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

Form laravel github  [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19292):

> That's just a helper for the most simple case for defining both the morph id and morph type columns. If you need more control, they can be assigned individually.

You're better off doing it manually,

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('attachable_id')->nullable();
$table->string('attachable_type')->nullable();
```

Comment: @jones did you check directly in your DB that the field is marked as nullable ?

Comment: In my DB, its default value is null

Comment: @jones then how are you getting `Field 'attachable_id' doesn't have a default value`. cause that's an error from the DB.

Comment: Got it, my test_db not updated, because temporary I've commented `RefreshDatabase`, and new changes to migration not affected on that. I've checked that development db is changed, but test db is not and found the reason.

Comment: @jones if you're doing it manually, check if the Ids you're referencing are `unsignedBigInteger` or `unsignedInteger`.

Comment: For the record, `nullable()` results in a `default null` column spec, and the `nullableMorphs()` helper does create `nullable()` fields. So you don't need to do this manually

Answer (score 1):

Use `attachable_id` in fillable array in `Attachment` model.

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['attachable_id'];
}
```

**Note: Make sure in table attachable_id is nullable.**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify `fillable` attribute on the model

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
      //only the field names inside the array can be mass-assign
      protected $fillable = ['attachable_id']; 
}
```

More details: What does “Mass Assignment” mean in Laravel ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel/49669781))

---

In your migration you can do this to make the column nullable:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('attachable_id')->nullable();
    });
}
```

`->nullable()` Designate that the column allows NULL values ([Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns))