# My post method does not receive data in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I wanted your help, because I create some routes in the controller with laravel --resource and when I receive the data by $request and insert it into my database, I do not receive data. And I forgot to mention that it is an api in laravel.

Here is my route code

```
    Route::resource('blog', App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class)->only(['index','store','update','show','destroy']);
```

Here is my controller API code

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $blog = Blog::create($request->post());
        return response()->json([
            'blog'=>$blog
        ]);
    }
```

here I attach the capture after putting `print_r($request->all());` look what appears to me

Trace:
[image: Error image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: what happens is that when I send the data to my api and print it to see what I have sent; supposedly I have not sent anything

Comment: Use the `request()->all()` global helper. Also, check the request object's class. Also, check on insomnia if the request body is sending parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Mass Assignment" mean in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a little more information for SO members to help find the error and help with the solution.

I can point you to a few places in order to solve these issues

1. Does the request inputs match the fields in the databases?
2. Is there a validations rule that is not met and preventing the data from saving?
3. Use a try and catch block to check the output.
4. You can check the storage/log/laravel.log if there is an error that has been logged there.

Comment: friend what more information do you need I add it

Comment: My error is that when I make a post request to my api in the store controller I only receive data and save it without any validation yet and when I do a console.log() of what I received it comes out empty

Comment: Is the data saved in the database?

Comment: no friend as error message tells me that it cannot save because the data is null

Comment: I guess you should print_r($request->all()) in the  store function to check the input maybe one of the inputs is not captured.

Comment: I already added the result of what you told me to the question and I get an empty array, what can I do?

Comment: The problem is the request is sent as json but not form data so the $request is not receiving please send the data through the API as a form data

Answer (score 0):

The error is from insomnia I guess.

We can check here using two approaches:

1. On Insomnia you are sending JSON in the wrong format:

   ```
   {
    'key':'value'
   }
   ```

   Strings are not being used properly in JSON. Thus, you should send JSON this way.Check this out. Also, you can notice on your insomnia you are getting errors. Thus, because of invalid JSON it might not be sending the request body parameters.

   ```
   {
    "key":"value"
   }
   ```
2. Try sending the request body using `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`.