# multiple images not storing in database

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload multiple images on database but its not storing. when I var_dump the data I see the images but it's not storing in database.

the code for store the data is---

```
$ad = AdList::create([
    "userId" => $userId,
    "adTitle" => $request->data['title'],
    "photos" => json_encode($imageList),
]);

var_dump($ad);
```

And the I got after var_dump is---

```
["photos"]=>
    string(51) "["dodo (1)_1668406861.webp","dodo_1668406862.webp"]"
```

what is the reason for not storing in database? I am using laravel & vue

Ad_list model---

```
class AdList extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Sluggable;
    protected $guarded = [];

    // public $incrementing = false;
    // protected $table = 'ad_lists';
    // protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId','id');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'catId','id');
    }
    public function subcategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'subCatId','id');
    }
    public function businessPage(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BusinessPage::class, 'userId','userId');
    }

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'url' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check your column table name if the same in your model

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your table is not connected to your model. Try to add this:

> protected $table

```
    class AdList extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Uuid;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $table = 'adlist_table';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $guarded = [];



}
```

Try to add  protected $table = ''adlist_table" in your model;

Comment: It's not working. the other fields are storing but the photos are not stroring

Comment: or maybe your photos column is not included in fillable property?

Comment: Can you show me your AdList model?

Comment: Or double check your column table name if the same in your model